# MPI(MPJ Express) в Java(IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mpi

**Приветствую всех!**
Хочу научится пользоваться технологией MPI в Java но не знаю как создать даже простую программу с использованием MPJ Express библиотек.
Довольно много гуглил но не получил достаточно информации.
Хотелось бы увидеть подробное руководство по созданию простой программы в IntelliJ IDEA.
P.S. Статьи на английском тоже приветствуются.
*Заранее благодарен и не судите строго!*

Comment: Если нет примеров на основе IntelliJ IDEA то я не против посмотреть также на Eclipse и NetBeans

Comment: Вот тут даже кино есть http://mpjexpress.blogspot.ru/2010/12/debugging-parallel-applications-with.html Собственно отладку предваряет установка MPJ и составление программы. Как установить MPJ расписано в руководстве пользователя по MPJ . Как подключить библиотеки в ide ищите в руководствах по ide. Как составлять программы в ide - там же.

Comment: @Sergey благодарю за видео, очень помогло